# Even after enabling CORS in .NetCore API gives CORS error

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-s3, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.Net Core API and Angular as front end, where I have to enable CORS for .Net Core API, below is the code that I have tried:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Enable Cors
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
}
```

and

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Add Cors
   services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
   {
     builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));
}
```

but still, if I access the Angular app in the browser then it shows below error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my_testdomain/api/login' from origin 'http://my-angularapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

[image]

More details:

I am using AWS to publish both the application and both application lies under two different Buckets.

Starup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebAPI.Entities;
using WebAPI.Installers;
using WebAPI.Options;
using WebAPI.Validator;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            InstallExtensions.InstallServicesInAssembly(services, Configuration);
            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
                c.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddFluentValidation();
           
            services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v0", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "swagger", Version = "v0" });
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "swagger", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            var swaggerOption = new SwaggerOption();
            Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SwaggerOption)).Bind(swaggerOption);
            app.UseSwagger(options =>
            {
                options.RouteTemplate = swaggerOption.JsonRoute;
            });

            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                foreach (var uiEndpoint in swaggerOption.SwaggerUIEndpoints)
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint(uiEndpoint.Endpoint, uiEndpoint.Description);
                }
            });
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseMvc();
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your endpoint settings, or you could add `endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors(MyPolicy);`

Comment: The position of app.UseCors() also matters, we need to see the whole Configure method.

Comment: @juunas Thanks for the having a look on the question, I have added the startup.cs file in the question

Comment: @RabbyHasan Added the startup.cs

Comment: @juunas Do I need to add an attribute for controller level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just add the below code after the app.UseHttpsRedirection() in the Configure method:

```
app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

You should also remove other codes related to Cors in the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Thanks will check and let you know